# How can I change my code so that the output will be equal to all the data elements in the nodes?

Tags: c

I learned linked list today and tried this code. I wanted to 5 input values to the list using a for loop. At the bottom of the for loop, "head = head->next"
advances the head pointer to the next node in the list and when the loop terminates,the last node in the list has its .next field set to NULL to mark the end of the list and the while loop is then used to output the list. But as I compiled and run the code the output values of the list are NOT THE SAME ! as the input value. Where am I going wrong here?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    struct node{
    int data;
    int key;
    struct node* next;
    };

    struct node* head=NULL;


    int main(){

    int i;
    int a;
    int b;
    head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));//allocated memory

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    head->data=a;
    head->key=b;
    head->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head=head->next;
    }
    head->next=NULL;

    int j;
    struct node* m;
    m=head;


        while(m!=NULL){
            printf("%d %d ",m->data,m->key);
            m=m->next;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Your insertion process is faulty.

Comment: Youi have to keep the pointer to the head and extend the tail. What you doing is keeping the pointer to the last valid element you have inserted.

Comment: Ok thank you. But I am having confusion what I need to do to get the correct output?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then **use the debugger** `gdb` to run your program step by step, query its state, hence understand its behavior. Draw the memory state on a board (with arrows for the pointers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comments in below codes and try to understand your mistakes. Also this is not the way you are creating a link list and adding a node into it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
int data;
int key;
struct node* next;
};

struct node* head=NULL;


int main(){

int i;
int a;
int b;
head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));//allocated memory
//above you have create a node and head is pointing to it
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    head->data=a;
    head->key=b;
    head->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    //till above code it was find
    head=head->next;//but here you did the mistake, now head it pointing to the newly created node and you lost the address of first node
    //finally when you created the list with 5 nodes head is actually pointing to the last node of the list
  //hence it will print only the last node of the list
}
  //now do some modification and rewrite the for loop like below
/*
 struct node* p=head;
 for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    p->data=a;
    p->key=b;
    p->next=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p=p->next
} */

// head->next=NULL; //also change this line with below line of code
  p->next = NULL;    
 int j;
 struct node* m;
 m=head;
    while(m!=NULL){
        printf("%d %d ",m->data,m->key);
        m=m->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way of doing insertion at the end of the linked list:

```
void insertend(int a,int b)
        {
            current=head;
            struct list * temp=(struct list*) malloc(sizeof(list));
            temp->data=a;
            temp->key=b;
            temp->next=NULL;
            while(current->next!=NULL)
            current=current->next;
            current->next=temp;
            current=temp;
        }
```